How do I need to change my code to make it compatible with PAC/BTI?
I have written some arm64 assembly code following the AAPCS64 calling convention.
Now I would like to integrate this code into a C/C++ project built with PAC and BTI enabled.  I first noticed trouble when the linker told me that I was missing the GNU_PROPERTY_AARCH64_FEATURE_1_BTI property:
ld: error: md5block_arm64.o: -z bti-report: file does not have GNU_PROPERTY_AARCH64_FEATURE_1_BTI property

While it would be trivial to just set this property, I am aware that I likely need to change parts of my code to make them PAC/BTI aware.  What are the changes needed for this?  I am interested in a general answer that can be used as a guide to adapt any code, hence the lack of code to be adapted in this question.

"a project built with PAC and BTI enabled." In what language, with what compiler and options, under what ABI?

@NateEldredge C/C++, built with gcc or clang using the SysV ABI / AAPCS64.  The option -mbranch-protection=standard is used to enable PAC and BTI.

BTI is pretty simple, and doesn't depend on software ABI (beyond BTI being enabled in the first place). In the current version (K.a) of the manual, the behaviour is documented in section "D8.4.5.3 PSTATE.BTYPE". In essence:

Forward-edge branching instructions fall into two categories:

br, braa, braaz, brab and brabz
blr, blraa, blraaz, blrab, blrabz

I will be using br and blr as a short-hand for these categories.

There are three new instructions: bti c, bti j and bti jc.

blr branches must land on a bti c or bti jc instruction.

br branches that use a register other than x16 and x17 for the target address must land on a bti j or bti jc instruction.

br branches that use x16 or x17 for the target address can land on any bti instruction.

paciasp and pacibsp act as either bti c or bti jc based on some bits in SCTLR_ELn for the relevant translation regime - just assume bti c to be safe.


So in order to be compatible with BTI code, you have to:

Prefix all your functions that can be invoked via indirect branch with either paciasp, pacibsp or bti c.
Make sure that all tail calls and imports (just the ones using br to call actual functions) use x16 or x17.
Add bti j to all possible targets of switch-style brs.


PAC is an entirely different beast. That depends on the exact ABI of everything in your stack - gnu vs musl, C vs C++, __attribute__ specifiers in header files, ...
The AAPCS64 specification does not define a pointer authentication ABI at all. PAUTHELF64 has some definitions for how to encode things in the ELF file format, but crucially it doesn't define how those things are to be chosen.
Basically any code pointer synthesis, any indirect branch, and potentially even memory loads might need PAC instructions - entirely implementation-defined.
Now, lucky for you, -mbranch-protection=standard seems to use PAC just barely at all. From the documentation of the flag:

-mbranch-protection=none|standard|pac-ret[+leaf+b-key]|bti
Select the branch protection features to use. none is the default and turns off all types of branch protection. standard turns on all types of branch protection features. If a feature has additional tuning options, then standard sets it to its standard level. pac-ret[+leaf] turns on return address signing to its standard level: signing functions that save the return address to memory (non-leaf functions will practically always do this) using the a-key. The optional argument leaf can be used to extend the signing to include leaf functions. The optional argument b-key can be used to sign the functions with the B-key instead of the A-key. bti turns on branch target identification mechanism.

Basically this only uses PAC to protect stack frames, which does not affect the ABI between different compilation units at all. If you want to uphold the security properties of the option, then all of your functions that spill x30 will need a paciasp before the spill and an autiasp between the reload and the ret. (If your code does not need to be able to run on hardware without PAC support, you can combine the autiasp+ret into a single retaa).
